# Subset of finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A \subseteq G$. Suppose $2 |A| > |G|$. Prove that $G$ is equal to $AA$. $\left(AA = \{xy\mid x \in A\land y \in A\}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g \in G$ be given. Then the sets $A$ and $gA^{-1} = \{ga^{-1} : a \in A\}$ are not disjoint, because $$|A| + |gA^{-1}| = |A| + |A| > |G|.$$ Choose $a \in A \cap g^{-1}A$ and $b \in A$ with $gb^{-1} = a$; then $g = ab \in AA$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:

For finite groups a non empty subset is a group iff it is closed under multiplication.

Hint 2:

What is the lowest cardinality $AA$ might have (use Lagranges theorem)

Comment: the lowest cardinality of AA can be |A|.

Comment: @stranger $AA$ is a subgroup of $G$

Comment: AA is subgroup of G then how can we imply G = AA?

Comment: @stranger by lagranges theorem we know $|AA|$ divides the cardinality of $G$. But as $2 \cdot |AA|> |G|$ we can conclude $|AA|=|G|$ and as $AA\subseteq G$ we can conclude $AA=G$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis But is it obvious that $AA$ is closed under multiplication?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is certainly not true in general that $AA$ is a group (look at $A = \{1\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where $AA = \{2\}$). Maybe there is a trick if you know that $|A| > |G|/2$